# Hypenation for slovakian language

Tags: hyphenation

I have problem i need hypenation for slovakian language, as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}
Do divadelnej štruktúry vstupujú viaceré druhy umenia ako jej zložky. Niektoré sú mimo divadla samostatnými umeniami (maliarstvo, hudba, architektúra), iné existujú len v divadle (herectvo, réžia).
\end{document}
```

"Niektoré" is divided as Niek-toré and not Nie-ktoré. How can i fix it, preferably with all similiar errors that can show up?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try `Nie\-ktoré` then

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to TeX.SX, or as we say here in Slovakia, vítaj :)

You can load the `\usepackage[slovak]{babel}` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}

\begin{document}
Do divadelnej štruktúry vstupujú viaceré druhy umenia ako jej zložky. Niektoré sú mimo divadla samostatnými umeniami (maliarstvo, hudba, architektúra), iné existujú len v divadle (herectvo, réžia).
\end{document}
```

That package contain hyphenation dictionary, that solves your problem. If you run into a word it cannot hyphenate properly, you can use  `\hyphenation` command you put in the preamble like this: `\hypenation{Naj-vy-ru-ka-vič-ko-va-nej-ší}`.